# Using phpqrcode library add url

Tags: php, url, qr-code

I want to create a QR CODE which will have url .

E.g :

```
Product Details :
Name : XYZ
Price : $43
Url : www.abc.com/rty
Description : Wonderful product
```

I managed to show this data , but not in that exact format . Mine (below) output on decode :

```
Product Details : \n    Name : XYZ \n    Id : 43 \n    Link : www.abc.com/rty \n     Description : Wonderful product
```

Please help .

*Phpqrcode library used .*

My Code :

```
    $contents = $producttype.'\n';
    $contents .= 'Name : '.$collection->getName().'\n';
    $contents .= 'Id : '.$collection->getId().'\n';
    $contents .= 'Link :'.Mage::getUrl().$collection->getUrlKey().'\n';
    $contents .= 'Description : '.$collection->getShortDescription().'\n';

    $imagename = 'qrcode' . md5($collection->getId()) . '.png';
    $filename = $PNG_TEMP_DIR.$imagename;

    QRcode::png($contents, $filename, $errorCorrectionLevel, $matrixPointSize, 2);
```

Data coming dynamic , one can easily assume .

Comment: When you echo this output, try first echoing "<PRE>";

\n represents a new line, but it needs to be rendered

Comment: Can you please provide some code that isn't working, its too unclear what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: @KHMKShore : Have updated it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok . Have done it .
For data to come to on second line , used `PHP_EOL`

```
QRcode::png("http://www.abc.com", "test.png", "L", 4, 4);
```

However , If I add the above code only then it gives **url type qrcode** .
Also the link part also depends upon the app which one uses to read QR code .